# jQuery append inputs - escaping attributes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm having this php script

```
$input = '<table id="options-table" border=0 cellpadding=6 cellspacing=0 class="data">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="first"></th>
                            <th>Value</th>
                            <th>Label</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td><input name="option_val[]" value="uk"></td>
                            <td><input name="option_label[]" value="United Kingdom"></td>
                            <td><a href="" class="button tiny">Remove</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- <tr>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td><input value="us"></td>
                            <td><input value="United States"></td>
                            <td><a href="" class="button tiny">Remove</a></td>
                        </tr> -->
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div style="margin-top:12px;">
                    <a onclick="$(\'#options-table tbody\').append(\'<tr><td>3</td><td><input name=\'option_val[]\' /></td><td><input name=\'option_label[]\' /></td><td></td></tr>\'); return false;" href="#" class="button" >Add option</a>
                </div>';
```

What I'd like to do is when I click the `Add option` button to append a `tr` on my table that holds the two `input` fields. The problem is that the hole table is inside a php string and not as plain html, so when I'm trying to escape the input attributes I'm getting a console error on firebug:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list


...nd('<tr><td>3</td><td><input type='text' name='option_val[]' /></td><td><input t...
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: It is 2016! Why do people still put loads of HTML inside PHP variables. It destroys the readability of your code and makes debugging a headache :(

Comment: I know.. :-( unfortunatelly this crap is in a website that I have to fix it and unfortunatelly don't have the time to do massive changes..

Comment: Use a delegated event handler to attach the click event. That way you can remove the ugly and outdated `onclick` event attribute from your code completely.

Comment: Ow, then I feel sorry for you, @Lykos. I have been in the same situation and I can feel your pain :(

Comment: @Rory McCrossan what do you mean? could you explain in details please ?

Comment: He means something like `$(document).on('click', 'a.button', yourAppendCodeHere());`

Comment: @Timothy Yes this seems to work better actually, thanks!

Comment: How can I delete a `tr` when I click one of the `Remove` buttons ???

Comment: If you click your remove button it will be available through `$(this)`, then just select the parent `tr` and remove it. `$(this).parents('tr').remove();`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This a basic html quote problem, if inside you will use html in that way `<input name=option_val[] >` 
then code will run without any javaScript error. Use this revised code, hope this one work for you

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php 
$input = '<table id="options-table" border=0 cellpadding=6 cellspacing=0 class="data">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="first"></th>
                            <th>Value</th>
                            <th>Label</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td><input name="option_val[]" value="uk"></td>
                            <td><input name="option_label[]" value="United Kingdom"></td>
                            <td><a href="" class="button tiny">Remove</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- <tr>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td><input value="us"></td>
                            <td><input value="United States"></td>
                            <td><a href="" class="button tiny">Remove</a></td>
                        </tr> -->
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div style="margin-top:12px;">
                    <a onclick="$(\'#options-table tbody\').append(\'<tr><td>3</td><td><input name=option_val[] ></td><td><input name=option_label[] ></td><td></td></tr>\'); return false;" href="#" class="button" >Add option</a>
                </div>';

echo $input;
```

Comment: Its working, however according to the sircumstances it makes more sence to use Tomothy's and Rory McCrossan solution. thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes this is not the correct way i given you a solution for your current situation. otherwise this is a old method

Answer (score 0):

Use double quote " instead of single '

example in

use

```
<input name=\"option_val[]\" /></td>
```

It's simply a quote problem on parsing